# Adding grouping in select dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I do have a dropdown of `items` which is fetched from db. So now I need to group it under categories, but every item won't be inside a category. So the desired result will be like this

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Foo</option>
    <option value="2">Bar</option>
    <optgroup label="Baz group">
        <option value="3">Baz 1</option> 
        <option value="4">Baz 2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Boo group">
        <option value="5">Boo 34</option> 
        <option value="6">Boo 23</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="7">Qux</option>
</select>
```

Using `grouped_collection_select`, `grouped_options_for_select` will handle the default options as another groups.

How can I generate it using Form builder select helpers?

Comment: My best guess is using grouped_collection_select on the form_builder: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select

Comment: @royvandermeij : But the problem is, it need to iterate over items and group it as many items don't have a group.